# Repeated array in parent template using Twig and Slim

Tags: php, frameworks, twig, slim

I've just started using Slim and Twig and getting to grips with it all.

I am building a small site and will have a Twitter feed on every page. So, I want to put this in my layout template (base.html.twig). The only way I can see to do it is to pass it in to every route and then use an include that can access the details.

Seems like there must be a way to set it in the layout template once without passing it in through every route?

Any help or a related link would be great.

Comment: why not make something like sidebar.html.twig that is already in layout?

Comment: But if I'm using say 'contact.html.twig', extending 'base.html.twig' I can't access the twitter object in the parent template without passing it through contact.html.twig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can extend twig with user defined functions, just make a call inside template and you will not need for passing it every time http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#creating-an-extension

Comment: Great, that looks like what I'm after. I'll give it a crack tomorrow!